# Javascript: Datatables stateLoadCallback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm trying to implement [Datatables 1.10.13. stateLoadCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) where in JS I have this

```
stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
  $.ajax( {
   url: '/common/datatables_states/'+contname+'.json',
   async: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function (json) {
   callback( json );
   }
 } );
}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/en/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json` I see this:

```
[
  {
    "id": null,
    "state": "{\"time\":\"1494765237165\",\"start\":\"0\",\"length\":\"10\",\"order\":{\"0\":[\"0\",\"asc\"]},\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"},\"columns\":{\"0\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}},\"1\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}},\"2\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}}}}"
  }
]
```

however I don't see any state loaded from DB in my terminal.
**I'm wondering what am I missing here, please?** Is my JS and JSON response good?